# Opción de menú contextual del explorador de archivos pase todos items seleccionados en un array de string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

A ver si pudiérais ayudarme por favor.

Estoy haciendo una prueba, para luego incorporar el código resuelto en otra aplicación. Se trata de usar una opción en el menu contextual del explorador de archivos para luego poder procesar archivos y/o carpetas con la aplicación. He logrado crear la opción en el menu contextual del esplorador de archivos, para cualquier tipo de archivos usando el comodín `*`.

Lo que sucede es que le pasa el nombre del archivo a la aplicación indicada en el `Value` del registro creado al respecto, pero solo le pasa el `path` de un archivo. Y yo lo que quiero es que si selecciono 20 archivos y/o carpetas le pase a la aplicación un array o lista o lo que sea conveniente, con todos los path de todos los archivos y carpetas seleccionados a la aplicación.

Hasta el momento, se claramente que el código que he usado no logra hacer lo que quiero, pero lo pongo igualmente por si sirve de algo para hallar una solución. Gracias.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\shell\expContextMenu");
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\shell\expContextMenu\command");
            key.SetValue("", (Application.ExecutablePath+" %1"));
        }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"*\shell\expContextMenu\command");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(@"*\shell\expContextMenu");
        }
```

Comment: Quizás quieras leer [esto (inglés)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1822850/5622844), dice que aparentemente no es posible, pero, probablemente funcione si creas una aplicación intermediaria que reciba cada uno de los archivos, los escriba en un archivo de texto y luego los pase como parametros a la otra aplicación.

Comment: Entendido, gracias

Answer (score -1):

fijate en OpenFileDialog tiene la opción filenames que es un array con los nombres de los archivos seleccionados

```
OpenFileDialog fichero = new OpenFileDialog();
if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    fichero.FileNames <<<--- este es un array
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. El OP en ningun caso está utilizando un `OpenFileDialog`, si no que recibe los nombres de ficheros desde el explorador de windows mediante un menu contextual.

Comment: El nombra una aplicación y que quiere pasarle a la misma un conjunto de archivos seleccionados mediante el explorador, pensé que estaba usando el OpenFileDialog y que solo le faltaba encontrar "FileNames" con la (s) al final

Comment: Conozco eso. Verás ya hay un visor de elementos en la aplicación para la que quiero esto, pero mi proposito es poder aplicarla desde el explorador de archivos, porque su desempeño está relacionado con el procesamiento y gestión de archivos, abiertamente a cualquier tipo de archivos. En la aplicación principal no usé openFileDialog porque no me permitía seleccionar archivos y carpetas a la vez. Pero eso es otra cosa.